# Is Ethtrade.org real deal or a scam?

Tags: ether

I would like to ask about ethtrader.org.

Could anyone prove please, that they are not a scam and part of the ethereum community?

Many thanks...

Comment: 250 % profit per year. I'm sure it's not legit. No imprint, whois protection. However it's also co-hosted by a czech guy called [Pavel Ducho](https://pavelducho.cz/). Maybe send him a message and ask directly?

Comment: It's not really clear to me if it's a scam or not but I walked the whole site and I don't have a good feeling about this. No real proofs, but that's what's confusing. It's blurry. An honest business would show clear honesty proofs since home page. Here the use all sorts of references that could make all this seem serious like investors statuses with Ethereum releases names or logo of known projects like Augur, digix, ... But they don't have any relationship.You could ask Slock.it if they are partners but I think I know the answer.

Comment: what is their eth address ?

Comment: I'd ask them their eth address, then transaction reports. from their FB page they seem to use Kraken, Kraken provides transaction logs, so those can be crossed with the real ETH/USD price. As a rule of thumb, too good promises are often not real. they don't explain anything about the trading strategy their using, which seems fishy, the dedication they put on building that site is rather impressive though